# How do i nest div elements in HTML?

Tags: loops, html, nested, haml

is there a possibility to code a loop in HTML to nest div elements in that way(the child elements are the interesting ones):

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="child">...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the main language of your project, but a simple solution that comes to mi mind and think it works is doing something like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <% simple for statement in your main languaje %>
        <div class="child">
    <% end %>

    <% same simple for statement in your main languaje %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```